# Asp.net - Mvc Get link redirected from a another link

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to capture a image link from a link/

For example:

In Html file response, I cature a link that looks like
**http://images1.tuoitre.vn/tianyon/ImageView.aspx?ThumbnailID=639445**

it display an image in the browser.
When I paste it into the browser, it redirects to address image link. **http://images1.tuoitre.vn/Tianyon/Cache/Image/445/639445.jpg**

So, I can not download image from **http: //images1.tuoitre.vn/tianyon/ImageView.aspx?ThumbnailID=639445**. I only know how to download images form a direction address as **http: //xxx.jpg**

Is there any way to capute **http: //xxx.jpg** to address link **http: //xxx.aspx?ThumbnailID=639445**

Thank you so much!

Comment: We're not sure what you are asking here. Can you explain further please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, you want to download the image from URL right? then try below Action in your controller.

```
public FileStreamResult DownloadImg()
        {
            string aURL = "http://images1.tuoitre.vn/Tianyon/Cache/Image/445/639445.jpg";
            Stream rtn = null;
            HttpWebRequest aRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(aURL);
            HttpWebResponse aResponse = (HttpWebResponse)aRequest.GetResponse();
            rtn = aResponse.GetResponseStream();

            return File(rtn, "image/jpeg","Image_1");

        }
```

**View:**

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadImg", "{YourControllerName}")
```